# How can I produce continuous signal from short one?

Tags: multivibrator

Can somebody explain, please. How can I produce continuous signal from short one?
[image]

Comment: Please clarify your question, including some numbers (e.g. expected input frequency/pulse width and expected output pulse width). I don't see a continuous signal, just one with a different duty cycle.

Comment: IN looks like a continuous signal to me ... you are wanting to change the `duty cycle` of a signal

Comment: Looks like you want a "pulse stretcher" Put those words into a search engine.

Comment: My picture isn't accurate enough. I have, for example, some signal width pulse width PW~5ns, how can I get signal 5-7ns wider, for example. There are some circuit like an edge detector.... I'm just interected if there some circuit where I can get output signal with specific width? Something like that ?

Comment: A warm welcome to the site. People will not give you answers. Instead, they will help you take the next step if your question shows you've already done as much as you possibly could - which yours doesn't, I'm afraid. Please edit your question and greatly improve it. Show your own work and own findings in considerable detail with any schematic. The schematic tool here is easy to use. The better the quality of your question, the better the quality of the answers it will attract. Again, welcome.

Comment: You said you wanted a continuous signal in your title and that isn't compatible with a pulse stretcher.

Comment: If you want to delay the negative edge 6ns but 0ns for the +ve , you need a CML one shot gate circuit with 0.1ns delay on rising edge and invert the output again back into a 6ns delay= dt = CdV/Ic using CML logic current. Did I understand?

Comment: Did you search for "pulse stretcher" as Brian suggested? That's probably what you need.

Comment: Is this a BiPhase decoder or ?

Comment: Thanks, I've already found. It's definetly pulse stretcher.